# How to call C# dll which works on multi threads from Python 2.7(pythonnet)?

Tags: c#, python, multithreading, python.net

Currently I am working on project in which I need to call the C# dll which works on threads from Python 2.7 by using pythonnet.
By using CLR I could able to call normal C# dll.
But facing issues to call the C# dll which works on threads.

### **Update:**

I could able to solve the issue.
In C# code, we were calling threads to read and write, but what was happening was sometime Main thread was exiting before the child thread.
So I used **Join()**, which allow main thread to wait until the completion of child threads.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Comment: `facing issues` - what does that mean ? Any error messages ? How are we supposed to help you when we don't even know what the problem is ?

Comment: C# dll is to copy a file from one location to other location.
To increase the performance of copying we are using 2 different threads to read and write.
First read thread will call which reads chunk of a file and will be storing into the buffer, once the buffer is full write thread is called to copy it to destination.
Same dll if I call it through python, it is behaving differently means threads are not calling in proper order. sometime either of one thread is calling and exiting.
So it is not copying the file to destination.